# Communication complexity of equality gap problem

Tags: approximation, lower-bounds, communication-complexity

I'm interested to know what is the biggest known $0\le \epsilon\le 1$ such that the $gap-EQUALITY$ problem that is defined by:

$$f_\text{GEQ}(x,y)=\cases{1&$x=y$\\0 & $x$ and $y$ differ in at least $\epsilon\cdot n$ positions\\\text{undefined}&otherwise}$$

Still requires $\Omega(n)$ communication bits?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $\epsilon < 1/2$, you can pick a code with exponentially many codewords and minimum distance $\epsilon n$. If the inputs are promised to be in the code, your problem becomes EQUALITY, and so requires $\Omega(n)$ communication.

When $\epsilon = 1$, the problem becomes easy (send the first bit).

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to distributed computation and communication complexity, so this was really helpful. It seems my intuition was correct about this problem, even though I managed (alone) to prove only for $\epsilon \le \frac{1}{3}$. Knowing this holds for all $\epsilon<1$ is really useful!

Comment: Doesn't theorem 1.4 state that only for $\eta n\le l\le (\frac{1}{2}-\eta) n$ this holds? this would mean that $l\le \frac{1}{2} n$, but $l=\epsilon n$ in this case. So wouldn't that imply that this proof works only for $\epsilon \le \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: You seem to be right. In that range there is a simple argument - take a good code.

Comment: Cool, then if we work with error correcting codes, why is it necessary that $\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$? can't we construct an error correcting code with a bigger distance that still would make the codewords in size $O(n)$?

Comment: Unfortunately, a code with minimum distance larger than $n/2$ has constant size.

Comment: Im struggling to see why we cant use some code, say the Reed Solomon code, and transform a word of length $n$ to a bigger length $cn$, and then the distance would be $cn-n+1$. By choosing $c$ correctly, can't we achieve a distance of $\epsilon n$?

Comment: Maybe this suits another question in the CS SE. Thanks! :)

Comment: Reed-Solomon codes are not necessarily binary.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Varshamov_bound_for_linear_codes#Gilbert%E2%80%93Varshamov_bound_theorem gives us a strong code that will allow us to create the reduction?

Comment: You can also just take a random code.