# Existence of good error correcting codes

Tags: reference-request, error-correcting-codes

I recently asked [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/141145/communication-complexity-of-equality-gap-problem/141152?noredirect=1#comment297503_141152) and got an answer from Yuval Filmus stating that we can build a solution using error-correcting codes.

More specifically, I'm looking for error correcting codes (for binary alphabet) with **constant** $R>0$ non-zero **relative** rate, and as high as possible **relative** distance $\delta$.

I know that using [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Varshamov_bound_for_linear_codes#Gilbert%E2%80%93Varshamov_bound_theorem), we can achieve any $\delta < \frac{1}{2}$. As pointed out by Yuval Filmus's answer to my last question, this is the best $\delta$ we can hope for.

Where can I find a proof that states there is no binary error-correcting code with a relative distance bigger than $\frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the [Plotkin bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotkin_bound).

Comment: Thanks! this was really helpful to me :)